# php force download pdf from a dynamic link and store to local folder

Tags: php, pdf, download, mime-types

I am building a script that imap's into a google mailbox, gets a message, and extracts a link from the body. The link, when opened via php, starts a download process of a PDF file from an external source.

Here is what I need to do:

1. Programmatically open the link which initiates a download
2. Download the PDF, bypassing any dialog boxes obviously
3. Store the PDF file to a local folder on the web server

I have been successful up to the point where I can initiate the download process and download the file. However, every attempt at opening the PDF finds the file to be corrupted and I can't figure out why. Here's what I'm trying now. The following is based on similar topics.

```
    $filename =  http://cckk.ca/KE645R26/geico.com_SEO_Domain_Dashboard_20121101_00.pdf

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
```

I am thinking that maybe there's an issue with the filename I'm passing?

**Note:** This script will be setup as a CRON task that is run on the server every few seconds, in order to constantly fetch from OUR own mailbox, so this is not going to have any type of user interaction or be a security risk to a user.

Comment: Let me edit the script purpose to clarify that question...

Comment: Sorry, it is clear now what you are wanting to do. I at first thought by local, you meant a local person's HDD via Browser, but I see now you said web server. I think you should look at the curl functions of PHP for getting remote files.

Comment: But from everything I have seen, examples use Content Headers to fetch files, or is my application not for the same purpose?

Comment: Use content headers to output the file to a browser (or something else making a REQUEST for that content-type). If you are simply getting a remote file, and then writing it locally, you don't need to send any headers.

Comment: @crush True, but he does need the `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; ...` to prompt the download.

Comment: I don't see why he would need that? He is simply grabbing a remote file, and saving it locally.

Comment: So the second example from this page would suffice? http://www.phpriot.com/articles/download-with-curl-and-php

Comment: I think Listing 1 on that page would suffice.

Comment: Clarify please. Do you want this to save a remote pdf to your server, or should this prompt a user to download the pdf?

Comment: I want it to automatically download to the web server. I'm using the curl example at the above link and getting success. I don't know why I was trying to do this with content headers, makes no sense now that I look back. Thanks all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$filename = 'http://cckk.ca/KE645R26/geico.com_SEO_Domain_Dashboard_20121101_00.pdf';

file_put_contents(
    '/your/server/path/folder/' . basename($filename), // where to save file
    file_get_contents($filename)
);

exit;
```

Comment: giving you the check since technically you were the only one with an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use filesize() on remote files. Most likely, the errors from that call are showing up at the beginning of the file and thus corrupting it.